# Spring Batch Intellij gives error due to version. ( Just error Ultimate version )

Tags: spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, spring-batch

I am trying to create a Spring Batch project. And I am creating the project.

However, after purchasing intelllij idea ultimate version, my project started giving errors. I downloaded the "community" version again and my project is working :)

So what is the problem?

If I want to run my spring batch project with intelllij idea ultimate 2022.2 version. I cannot access any spring batch objects like JobBuilderFactory, StepBuilderFactory, ItemWriter, ItemReader etc.

But if I run the same project with the free version "community" there is no error and the project works.

I can't help going crazy :)

[Could not autowire. No beans of 'JobBuilderFactory' type found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyTqC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project that worked in the CE version did not work in the Ultimate version. However, the problem was solved as follows.

I added @EnableBatchProcessing annotation in Spring Boot Application class and I think it included it in the context.

NOTE : Usually in batch applications, @EnableBatchProcessing anotation is included in the configuration class.

When I included it directly in the main class, the problem was solved. It was a strange error.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because IntelliJ Idea is not able to detect that `EnableBatchProcessing` is importing these beans and adding them to the application context. This error is only a hint from the IDE. If you run the project with the ultimate edition, it should work as well.

There should be a difference between the community and ultimate edition WRT how to report this kind of errors, but if your app runs with the CE, it should also run with the UE.